# How can I return if an optional navigation property exists from an Entity Framework Query?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to return a boolean value using the following query:

```
var q = from inmate in context.Inmates
        select new
        {
            inmate.Id,
            IsCrazy = inmate.Certified != null
        };
```

`IsCrazy` should be `true` only when the optional `Certified` navigation property is not null. However, `IsCrazy` is always being returned as true, regardless of whether there's a link between`Inmate > Certified`.

Using the above code and the following data:

```
Inmate { 1 } --> { Certified }
Inmate { 2 } --> NULL
Inmate { 3 } --> { Certified }
```

I was expecting the following results:

```
1, true
2, false
3, true
```

However, all the results come back true. What am I doing wrong?

I then tried to bring back the optional navigation property instead, but this appears to do an inner join and *only* returns the crazy inmates:

```
Inmate { 1 } --> { Certified }
Inmate { 3 } --> { Certified }
// Inmate 2 is missing
```

**EDIT: Forgot to mention, I am using EF 4.0 Code First.**

**EDIT 2:**

This is the SQL output

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
CASE WHEN (cast(1 as bit) <> cast(0 as bit)) 
THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN (1 = 0) THEN cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
FROM [dbo].[Inmate] AS [Extent1]
```

Looks totally wrong to me; there's no mentioned of `Certified` whatsoever.

**EDIT 3:**

I tried the following code in LINQPad (Dropping the inmate thing, this is my actual code):

```
from i in Ingredients
join m in Meats 
    on new { i.IngId, i.VersionId } equals new { m.IngId, m.VersionId } into temp
from t in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
    IngId = i.IngId,
    IsMeat = t.MeatTypeId == null ? false : true
};
```

This will return all 3000 results with the correct true/false values. The same code in Entity Framework will return only the results which have the one-to-one relationship fulfilled.

This is the SQL generated by LINQPad:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int SET @p0 = 0
DECLARE @p1 Int SET @p1 = 1
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[IngId], 
    (CASE 
        WHEN ([t1].[MeatTypeId]) IS NULL THEN @p0
        ELSE @p1
     END) AS [IsMeat]
FROM [Ingredient] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [MeatIngredient] AS [t1] ON ([t0].[IngId] = [t1].[IngId]) 
    AND ([t0].[VersionId] = [t1].[VersionId])
```

This is the SQL generated by EF:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[IngId] AS [IngId], 
cast(1 as bit) AS [C1]
FROM  [dbo].[Ingredient] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[MeatIngredient] AS [Extent2] 
    ON ([Extent1].[VersionId] = [Extent2].[VersionId]) 
        AND ([Extent1].[IngId] = [Extent2].[IngId])
```

Comment: This query should work as-is. Something else is going on here. Your syntax is correct.

Comment: Use LINQPad or `ObjectQuery.ToTraceString()` to see the generated SQL.

Comment: @Craig Stuntz - I can't see the method `ToTraceString` anywhere?

Comment: You need a reference of type `ObjectQuery`. You may need to cast. [But I assure you, it does exist.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring.aspx)

Comment: @Craig Stuntz - Got it. See the updated question with the included SQL.

Comment: What is Certified exactly? If if is a navigation property that is part of a one to many relationship. It will never be null but an EntityCollection.

Comment: @Vintharas - It's a 1-to-1 relationship. But an optional relationship. If I load up the inmate directly, then certified is null.

Comment: That suggests there's a problem with the mapping (or a CTP bug, I suppose).

Comment: @Craig Stuntz - I get the same problem in LINQPad.

Comment: Well, yes, I expect you would; LINQPad results are generally the same as the same query run in an app. Check your mapping, and try a similar query with one of the MS Code-First demos (i.e., with their mapping).

Comment: @Craig Stuntz - Actually, it appears it works in LINQPad and not in EF. Must be an EF bug.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "LINQPad and not in EF." LINQPad can use your EF model. Are you doing that?

Comment: @Craig Stuntz - Nope. Doesn't appear as though it works with Code First projects. Code First uses DbSet and LINQPad is looking for ObjectContexts. What I meant was, the same code in **EDIT 3** works perfectly in LINQPad and gives the 3000 results I'm expecting, but EF only returns 140 of 3000 results.

Comment: There is a `DbContext.ObjectContext` property. But that said, it won't tell you much as you already have the SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've managed to get it working as expected by thinking backwards. I.e. checking a nullable meat has an ingredient (or to still with the initial example, check that the certificate has a valid inmate):

```
var q = from i in context.Ingredients
        let m = i.Meat // AKA Certificate
        select new 
        {
            IngId = i.IngId,
            IsMeat = m.Ingredient != null 
        };
```

The SQL is nasty for such a simple query. It's about 4 times the size it would have been if I'd written the stored procedure myself. However, it runs in 57ms, so it's not much to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps. but try

IsCrazy = !inmate.Certified.Equals(System.DBNull.Value)

Comment: Nope. Doesn't help. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and try doing a left outer join :

```
var q = from inmate in context.Inmates
join c in Certified on inmate.cId equals c.Id into temp //replace with whatever you will join on
from temp in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { inmate.Id, IsCrazy = c.IsCertified != null }; //replace to what it is you want to check
```

It will be something like that.  For a more specific example it might help to know a little bit more about the database structure here.  Hope this helps though.

Comment: I thought the same already, but it doesn't help. See my latest edits.

Comment: Hmmm...now that is a very interesting find!